# GLassfish SSL Configuration Page Level

Tags: security, ssl, jakarta-ee, glassfish

How can I secure only some of the pages of a web application running on glassfish V3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add a filter further in configuration.
 [check it here](http://blogs.oracle.com/jluehe/entry/how_to_downshift_from_https)

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Security Settings</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SSL Pages</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description>CONFIDENTIAL requires SSL</description>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

change the url-pattern to whatever you need.

Comment: i want , when server serve secure.html page ,i want protocol to be automatically 'https'  from http  

i have configured glassfish for https and also added above configuration in web.xml  
but it retrieves the page in http only.

Comment: also using HTTP user should not be able to access that secured page

Comment: my SSL port is 8181
plain port is 8080
added redirect port=8181 in http-listener1
still not redirecting to HTTPS

Comment: We need to add a filter further in configuration.
http://blogs.sun.com/jluehe/entry/how_to_downshift_from_https

  but only one hazard is there.i am using it with richFaces. once it goes to HTTPS its not changing the page i mean if i perform post action it doesnt actually happens. but if i do it from the local bmachine's browser it works perfectly from remote browser it stucks with HTTPS its not changing after that